# Shopify Integration in android

Tags: android, shopify, graphql

Hi I have integrated shopify sdk into my app, now version has been changed so i have to migrate my api v2 into v3 for my android app. Here they have been using GraphQL Concepts Instead of REST APIs using for webservice call to fetch products and collections details.

here my code.

```
graphClient = GraphClient.builder(getActivity())
                    .shopDomain(shopUrl)
                    .accessToken(shopifyAPIKey)
                    //   .httpClient(httpClient) // optional
                    .httpCache(new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), "/http"), 10 * 1024 * 1024) // 10mb for http cache
                    .defaultHttpCachePolicy(HttpCachePolicy.CACHE_FIRST.expireAfter(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) // cached response valid by default for 5 minutes
                    .build();


            query = Storefront.query(rootQuery -> rootQuery
                    .shop(shopQuery -> shopQuery
                            .name()
                            .currencyCode()
                            .refundPolicy(refundPolicyQuery -> refundPolicyQuery
                                    .title()
                                    .url()
                            )
                    )
            );


            graphClient.queryGraph(query).enqueue(new GraphCall.Callback<Storefront.QueryRoot>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull GraphResponse<Storefront.QueryRoot> response) {

                    String name = response.data().getShop().getName();

                    System.out.println("Response of Shopify : " + response.data().toString());

                    System.out.println("Shop Name : " + name);


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull GraphError error) {

                    error.printStackTrace();

                    System.out.println("Shopify Error : " + error.getMessage());

                    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });
```

This code for querying to fetch collections and products

```
query = Storefront.query(rootQuery -> rootQuery
            .shop(shopQuery -> shopQuery
                    .collections(collectionCount, collectionConnectionQuery -> collectionConnectionQuery
                            .edges(collectionEdgeQuery -> collectionEdgeQuery
                                    .node(collectionQuery -> collectionQuery
                                            .title()
                                            .products(productCount, productConnectionQuery -> productConnectionQuery
                                                    .edges(productEdgeQuery -> productEdgeQuery
                                                            .node(productQuery -> productQuery
                                                                    .title()
                                                                    .productType()
                                                                    .description()
                                                                    .images(2, imageConnectionQuery -> imageConnectionQuery
                                                                            .edges(imageEdgeQuery -> imageEdgeQuery
                                                                                    .node(imageQuery -> imageQuery
                                                                                            .src()
                                                                                    )
                                                                            )
                                                                    )
                                                                    .variants(2, variantConnectionQuery -> variantConnectionQuery
                                                                            .edges(variantEdgeQuery -> variantEdgeQuery
                                                                                    .node(productVariantQuery -> productVariantQuery
                                                                                            .price()
                                                                                            .title()
                                                                                            .available()


                                                                                    )


                                                                            )
                                                                    )
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )));
```

Here i am new to GraphQL concept, so how can i get the product image url,price and other details? Please guide me to get the data whatever want about product and other details using this GraphQL

Comment: Have you done this project, I have started a new android studio project but unable to call a single API. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Though late here is the solution.

In the given code, you have created a graph client, provided your domain and API key. Next, you just have mentioned what all data you need via a query.

Now a call is required to the Shopify endpoint so that you can get the desired data.

```
QueryGraphCall call_products = graphClient.queryGraph(query);

        call_products.enqueue(new GraphCall.Callback<Storefront.QueryRoot>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull GraphResponse<Storefront.QueryRoot> response) {

                List<Storefront.ProductEdge> list_edge = response.data().getShop().getProducts().getEdges(); //List of products that you have in your store.

                for(int i=0;i<list_edge.size();i++){
                    Log.d(TAG,"product title: "+response.data().getShop().getProducts().getEdges().get(i).getNode().getTitle());
                    Log.d(TAG,"product id: "+response.data().getShop().getProducts().getEdges().get(i).getNode().getId());
                    Log.d(TAG,"product description: "+response.data().getShop().getProducts().getEdges().get(i).getNode().getDescription());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull GraphError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + error.toString());
            }
        });
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: I have started a new android studio project but unable to call a single API. Can you please help me ?